# New EC2 ubuntu user file permissions

Tags: apache-2.2, ubuntu, amazon-ec2, permissions

Hi I've just set up a new EC2 ubuntu server at AWS yay.

Im logged in as ubuntu@mydomain.com

first I installed mysql, php5 and apache2, no problem.

now I want to edit my /etc/apache2/sites-available/default file to setup where my domains should point to....

but It seems I dont have permissions to write to the file.. and I dont have permissions to change the file permissions either.

then I tried editing the default index.html file in /var/www/index.html... but I got the same error/problem

any ideas?

Comment: Please don't take this the wrong way, but you seem to be in need of a basic Unix tutorial. You don't seem to quite grasp two core concepts of Unix (a multi-user system, and file ownership/permissions). Bringing you up to speed on this is well beyond the scope of what can be done on a Q&A site like Server Fault.  Google can hook you up with some tutorials. There's also [a YouTube video about file permissions and ownership](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SWZj0gLhFL4) that might be useful.

Comment: you are quite right.. I am new to linux and using the CLI but im kind of learning by doing, or learning by messing up.

Comment: That's the best way to learn - but spending an hour or so with a basic tutorial (or even Linux for Dummies) will save you a man-month of messing up and make it a way more pleasant experience. (Or find a local Unix admin to mentor you - that's way better than books.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to become root.. So you can turn into root via

```
sudo su -
```

Or just run as root everytime you need permissions

```
sudo vi  /etc/apache2/sites-available/default
```